# Why draw(in: CGRect) draws border around ellipse when it should not?

Tags: ios, swift, uigraphicsimagerenderer

This is my simple function I use for drawing an image in context:

```
let renderer=UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 330, height: 330))
let img=renderer.image{ ctx in
    let circle=CGRect(x:0,y:0,width: 330, height: 330)
    ctx.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    ctx.cgContext.addEllipse(in: circle)
    ctx.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fill)
                
    let image = UIImage(named: "1")!
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 100, height: 100))
}
```

And the result is following:

[image]

As you can see there is output of `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` with border around ellipse. Why?  Border is not defined anywhere, but it is printed.

The image named `1` is the following one:

[image]

**NOTE:**

This issue appears only when compiling ios app. Using playground everything is fine and ok.

Comment: UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 330, height: 330))
let circle=CGRect(x:0,y:0,width: 330, height: 330)
    ctx.cgContext.setFillColor(backgroundColor.cgColor)
img.draw(in: CGRect(x: 80, y: 80,width: 100, height: 100 ))
Please look into this.

Comment: The code you show produces a solid-filled circle (I substituted `UIColor.blue` since you don't show what `backgroundColor` is). Can you provide enough code to actually produce what you're seeing?

Answer (score 3):

Does your `UIImageView` have a `cornerRadius` applied to its layer? That can cause a thin gray border like you see here. If you create a circular image, like you have with `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`, you should not need to do any masking or `cornerRadius` on the `UIImageView`.

---

If you only want to fill the path, and not stroke it, one could use [`fillPath`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcontext/2427156-fillpath/) rather than `drawPath`.

---

FWIW, you could also just bypass the CoreGraphics context and just [`fill`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624371-fill/) the oval directly:

```swift
let image = renderer.image { _ in
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 330, height: 330))
        .fill()
                
    UIImage(named: "1")!
        .draw(in: CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 100, height: 100))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>OK, the updated code still does not match.</s>

First, in your posted image, the background is not white.

Second, even accounting for that, there is no "edge" on the rendered `UIImage`.

So, I'm going to make a guess here....

Assuming you execute the `img = renderer.image { ....` code block, and then you set `imageView.image = img`, my suspicion is that you have something like this:

```
imageView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.height / 2.0
```

So, the **lightGray** "circle" is the lightGray background anti-aliased to the `.cornerRadius`.

I would be that if set:

```
imageView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

and **do not** set the layer's cornerRadius (no need to), your ellipse border will be gone.

If it's still there, then you need to provide some code that ***actually reproduces the issue***.

---

**Edit**

I'm still not seeing the "border" when setting the rendered image to an image view, but...

Doing some debug inspecting and using the "1" image you added, there ***IS*** a difference.

Try this, and see if it gets rid of the border:

```
let fmt = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
fmt.preferredRange = .standard
        
let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 330, height: 330), format: fmt)
```

You can then use either:

```
let img = renderer.image { ctx in
    let circle = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 330, height: 330)
    ctx.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    ctx.cgContext.addEllipse(in: circle)
    ctx.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fill)
            
    if let image = UIImage(named: "1") {
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 100, height: 100))
    }
}
```

or Rob's suggested:

```
let img = renderer.image { _ in
    UIColor.white.setFill()
    UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 330, height: 330))
        .fill()

    if let image = UIImage(named: "1") {
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 100, height: 100))
    }
}
```

Comment: no, its not the case with backgroundColor of UIImage;)

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk - see the **Edit** to my answer.